# Extract URL from HTML using Javascript and use it in a function

Tags: javascript, html-parsing

I need to extract URL `link` from html.

```
<a rel="nofollow" href="link" class="1">
```

There is only one such link on the whole page.

Then I need to add use it as `a.href` in this function:

```
function changespan() {
    var spans = document.querySelectorAll('span.image');
    for (var i = spans.length; i--; ) {
        var a = document.createElement('a');
        a.href = "http://domain.com";
        spans[i].appendChild(a).appendChild(a.previousSibling);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post your HTML where the 'link' needs to be extracted from?

Comment: If you know how to use `querySelectorAll`, what is the problem? oO

Comment: I just did few problems with formatting. Is marking links using class tag smart thing to do?

Comment: I do not know javascript syntax at all, so it would probably take a whole day for me to do this, and i guess this is a simple regex.  Isn't it?

Comment: @Zox marking nodes with classes is super smart things to do! But better give some more meaningful names to your classes. Instead of `1` it could be `external-link`, etc.

Comment: Got it, I use cl1, as I have multiple links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
function changespan() {
    var spans = document.querySelectorAll('span.image'),
        href = document.querySelector('.nofollow-link').href;
    for (var i = spans.length; i--; ) {
        var a = document.createElement('a');
        a.href = href;
        spans[i].appendChild(a).appendChild(a.previousSibling);
    }
}
```

but change you link class to something else then `1` it can't start with number:

```
<a rel="nofollow" href="link" class="nofollow-link">Link</a>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Tqv76/2/

Comment: Work very well. Thanks for tip that classes cannot start with numbers.

Comment: You are welcome. I would appreciate if you accepted the answer (and the previous).

Comment: I didn't know that there is this option. How would i combine functions changespan1 and another one lets say changespan2?

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementsByTagName("a")[0].getAttribute("href");
```

Comment: So I say a.href = document.getElementsByTagName("a")[0].getAttribute("href"); ?

Comment: I'd think so. Give it a go.

Comment: The [0] implies the first anchor in the page, so I'm not sure if that's appropriate in your case.

Answer (score 0):

```
function changespan() {
    var spans = document.querySelectorAll('span.image');
    for (var i = spans.length; i--; ) {
        var a = document.createElement('a');
        a.href = $(".1").attr('href');
        spans[i].appendChild(a).appendChild(a.previousSibling);
    }
}
```

Comment: 1) there is no jQuery. 2) Never do things like that (query DOM in loops).

Comment: All of us know that there is jQuery. Then why are you pretending like it is not existing ?

Comment: How do you know that OP has jQuery?

Comment: I have but as @dfsq said class name cannot start with a number.