# Dynamically Insert Links In Span Tag Using Javascript (around anchor text)

Tags: javascript, text, href

On a html page I have:

```
<span class="me">See More</span>
```

And I should process it using javascript to get this (create link out of text):

```
<span class="me"><a href="http://domain.com>See More</a></span>
```

Never mind 0 I figure out that it works well. My bad, sorry.

```
function changespan() {
var spans = document.querySelectorAll('span.image');
for (var i = spans.length; i--; ) {
    var a = document.createElement('a');
    a.href = "http://domain.com";
    spans[i].appendChild(a).appendChild(a.previousSibling);
}
}
```

Let me know what is appendChild(a) and .appendChild(a.previousSibling)?

Here is the demo: http://jsfiddle.net/8eK7z/1/

Comment: Works fine, you just have to call the function: http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/8eK7z/4/

Comment: Actually this work - solution is from here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15340071/dynamically-insert-links-inside-span-tag-using-javascript

Comment: Thanks I even figured it out myself few sec ago.